# How to get an a-tag to fullsize

Tags: html, css

it would be great, when I can click the `<li>` container and in it is the `<a>` ..

So my container is width: 100px and height: 100px but my  tag only width: 20px and height: 15px.

So I can only click on the text in the  tag.

Can I change that?

```
<li>
<a href="technology/sem/">SEM</a>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
.menu ul li {
    background-image: url("../images/menu_background.png");
    background-position: 1px center;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border-color: #000000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000000;
    float: left;
    font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 38px;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0 34px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.menu ul li a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    line-height: 35px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

that doesn't work..

Comment: By default the `<a>` tag is an inline element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set a block context property on it.

```
li a {
display:block;
}
```

Comment: @AlexKante Try adding the padding to the `<a>` tag and not the `<li>`

Comment: Then you have something else going on. Perhaps you could provide a link or a JSFiddle

Answer (score 4):

You should apply `display: block` to your 'a' tag

An example : http://jsfiddle.net/e49Tg/

Comment: Provide us a demo link to debug the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can try `li > a { display: block; }` in your stylesheet. Make sure you prefix the `li` with the appropriate `ul` class or selector, just so you keep your change isolated to that occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

I can't clearly get what your problem is, if you want an `<a>` tag to be sized, the solution is as proposed: the "display" property should be either "block" or "inline-block".

In case you want it to have the same size as the parent it should also have the size directives, like:

```
li a { display: block; width:100%; height: 100% }
```

and if you want it to be so when clicked, a pure css solution would be

```
li a:active {
  display: block; width:100%; height: 100%;
}
```

If this isn't answer to your question, explain more.